# How to make pre-selected checkbox in django?

Tags: python, django, forms

My form has `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget receiving user's preferences.
I want to show a pre-checked preference to user. 
I know there is one way to pre-check widget in the template. 
But I want to know a way to pre-check in the *view* individually.
How can I do that?

Comment: individually means controll individual checkbox in the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the values you want to be checked to [`initial` (see docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) when you instantiate the form:

```
MyForm(initial={
    'my_multi': ['a', 'b', 'c']
})
```

Comment: What's the meaning of 'my_multi'?

Comment: @user1924839 that's the name of your CheckboxSelectMultiple widget field, and a, b, c are the values you want checked.  You didn't provide any sample code so I had to make them up.

Answer (score 0):

```
import django
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
     option = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
```

It renders so

```
<tr><th><label for="id_option">Option:</label></th><td><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="option" id="id_option" /></td></tr>
```