# Pre-selecting multiple checkboxes in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314357/how-to-make-pre-selected-checkbox-in-django), but I tried the accepted answer and it did not work. Here's what's going on.

I have a form for tagging people in photos that looks like this:

*forms.py*

```
class TaggingForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset')
        super(TaggingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['people'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=queryset, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
...
```

*models.py*

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
...

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo)
...
```

I want users to be able to edit the tags on their photos after they initially tag them, so I have a page where they can go to view a single photo and edit its tags. For obvious reasons I want to have the already-tagged individuals' checkboxes pre-selected. I tried to do this by giving the form's initial dictionary a list of people I wanted selected, as in the answer to the question I linked above.

*views.py*

```
def photo_detail(request,photo_id):

    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=photo_id)

    initial = {'photo_id':photo.id, 'people':[p for p in photo.person_set.all()]}
    form_queryset = Person.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaggingForm(request.POST, queryset=form_queryset)
        # do stuff
    else:
        form = TaggingForm(initial=initial, queryset=form_queryset)
...
```

When I try to initialize people as in the above code, the form doesn't show up, but no errors are thrown either. If I take the 'people' key/value pair out of the initial dictionary the form shows up fine, but without any people checked. 
Also I'm using Django 1.5 if that matters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Comment: Am I missing something? That answer seems to just be introducing the concept of initial values, which I already set. It's just the initial value for the checkboxes that doesn't work, and I don't know what to give it if not a list of the objects I want checked.

Comment: Why not use django forms to do the work of settings initial values for you? Thats what I was trying to get at.

Comment: Sweet, setting the initial value in the form definition worked, although I have to pass the form an extra parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Answered your question. Feel free to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is simply use django forms to handle all of this for you. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values). Ideally it boils down to lettings djnago handle your forms and its validation and initial values.

Now this is actually a really good practice to get used to since, you're dissecting all your logic and your presentation. Its a great DRY principle.